# Java ArrayList -- Threads

Tags: java, arraylist, thread-sleep

As part of a project that I work on (using Java), I face the following issue: I would like to display n values. For the purpose of explanation, n = 10 (1 to 10). I generate a random number (in the range 1 to 10) and choose one number that I don't want to display. Suppose my random number is 5.

I display the numbers from 1 to 4 in main thread, and start another thread in which I sleep for 25msec. In the mean time, I store the numbers 6 to 10 in a temporary arraylist in main thread. After the sleep time for number 5 expires, I would like to access the elements in temporary arraylist and display them one by one.

I need help in transferring the control to the main thread with a signal that number 5's time expired that would allow me to proceed with displaying 6 to 10.

P.S.: After getting this one working, I need to extend this idea for multiple missing random numbers in a larger space like 1 to 10000 while I buffer the numbers between missed ones.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've tried? When you say 'I need help transferring the control to the main thread' you're being pretty vague.

Comment: Is this solution required to have 2 threads?  Since thread timing is almost impossible to pull off without large delays in processing time.

Comment: You could use a `CountDownLatch`.  Set the `CountDownLatch` to `1`.  The second thread would `countDown` after is has waited it's prescribed period.  Your main thread would simple call `CountDownLatch#await`.  This will pause the main thread if the second thread hasn't completed or continue if it has.  You could also use something like an `AtomicBoolean`, but that starts to get messy...

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you have an `ArrayList` called `displayNums` that contains all the numbers you want to display at the moment.

When the time expires (this is in the second thread)

```
synchronized (displayNums) {
    displayNums.addAll(heldNums);
}
myDisplayArea.repaint();
```

The only tricky part is that you need to wrap every access to `displayNums` in a `synchronized` block like this one.